# Asp.Net MVC2 Clientside Validation and duplicate ID's problem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-validate, client-side

I'm using MVC2 with VS2010

I have a view that has two partial views in it: "Login" and "Register"

both partial views contains the Email address field i use the following in both partial views:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmailAddress ) %><br /><%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress) %>
```

if i use both partial views on one page, it ends up having duplicate id's so validation happens across both views (even thopugh they are in seperate forms)

how can i go about eliminating this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some controls you can specify the HTML attributes in an overload like this:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmailAddress, new { id = 'my-unique-id" }) %>
<br />
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress, new { id = 'my-unique-id" }) %>
```

You can also either write your HTML by hand or use the older HTML helpers so you can add your own ID that way (you need to do this for `Html.LabelFor()` helpers)

```
<%: Html.TextBox( "EmailAddress", Model.EmailAddress, new { id = 'my-unique-id" } ) %>
```

Comment: surely there is a way to do this other than ditching the "HTML Helper For"  methods?