# ASP.NET MVC Binding to View Model as well as routed values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I know similar questions have been asked regarding complex model binding in ASP.NET MVC, but I am having a problem binding because of a lack of a sufficient prefix coming back on the POST and wondered if there were an easy solution.

I have a view Model that looks something like this:

```
public class ViewModel<Survey, Contact>
{
    public Survey Model { get; set; }
    public Contact Model2 { get; set; }
}
```

I then have an action method like this that accepts the POSTed

```
public ActionResult Survey(
    string id, string id2, SurveyViewModel<Survey, Contact> model)
{
    // code goes here...
}
```

In my form, the first two id's are from the URL route and I then have form code (using `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Model.SurveyName)` or similar), generated with names like this:

```
<input class="text-box single-line" id="Model_Email"
       name="Model.Email" type="text" value="" />
```

A post works if I change the name from `Model.Email` to `model.Model.Email`, but I am trying to avoid having to create a custom model binder.

Is there

1. A setting I can make in the view to change the name for all fields rendered in a view using the `@Html.EditorFor` typed view helpers?
2. Something I can change using the Bind attribute on the action that would allow it to default binding to that object?

The answer may be "build a custom binder", but I just wanted to pose the question before biting that off.

Thanks for the help. Best Regards,

Hal

Comment: Have you tried changing the name of your `Model` property? The model binder gets confused when models have properties named Model.

Comment: Similarly, have you tried renaming the model parameter in your action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass custom viewdata with custom HtmlFieldPrefix to view. Every control rendered with helper will have that prefix.

```
ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = "prefix here";
```

Take a look at this: [Forcing EditorFor to prefix input items on view with Class Name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606686/forcing-editorfor-to-prefix-input-items-on-view-with-class-name)

Comment: I ended up overriding OnActionExecuting and setting setting HtmlFieldPrefix there. As long as I name my posted view model the same thing as the prefix and any actions that accept it, things seem to work great.

Comment: I meant OnActionExecuted (post execution, not pre)